# Do I need a transit visa for Brazil?

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, transit-visas, brazil

I am an Indian passport holder studying in Guyana, South America. I am going back to India for vacation on August 28, 2018 for 3 months. I am transiting in Panama and Brazil. From Guyana to Panama is one PNR and from Panama to Brazil to Dubai to India is another PNR. I already have transit permission for Panama. Do I need a transit visa for Brazil?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Brazilian [Consulate-General Rotterdam website](http://roterda.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/News.xml):

> 12/04/2017
>   The Immigration authorities of Brazil informed that, from October 1st
>   2015 onwards, international travelers from countries that do not have
>   visa waiver agreements with Brazil will be required to present a
>   transit visa (VITRA) when passing through the Brazilian territory with
>   reservations from different airline companies to reach the final
>   destination.
>
> International travelers bearing a single booking (one airline
>   reservation) from the departure country to the final destination will
>   not need a transit visa to pass through the Brazilian territory. The
>   single booking may include different airline companies considering
>   that the companies may have flight sharing agreements.
>
> The transit visa will be required only to the above international
>   citizens traveling with more than one booking (more than one airline
>   reservation) issued by different airline companies with no flight
>   sharing agreements.

or, in my opinion, you can also find an answer in *[Indian citizen transiting in Brazil on the way to Peru. Is a transit visa required?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83563/indian-citizen-transiting-in-brazil-on-the-way-to-peru-is-a-transit-visa-requir)*